# Find path to current JVM

Tags: windows, java, jvm

I need to find the path to the current Java VM running on my Windows machine. How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Control Panel, and look for the Java control panel applet. In there click on the Java tab, and then the "View..." button. The window that pops up should have the paths to the Java VM executables.

Answer (score 2):

[procexp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can display the full path of executables.

Comment: Only, of course, if they are running. The JVM on Windows is not a daemon, though there is now a Java Quick Start process (jqs.exe) that is getting there.